# Layer name from background to 0

Tags: adobe-photoshop, layers

I open an image which is showing as a jpeg, then when I crop it, the layer name has automatically changed from background to 0. When I save the image it is saving it as a psd, so I have to go through the time consuming actions of doing "save as" everytime. Why is photoshop changing the layer name?
The only other option I have is to flatten the layer everytime. :-(

Comment: That's how it works.

Comment: You really really **never, ever** want to save a jpg as a jpg. It really degrades the image quality.

Comment: I've used Photoshop for over 20 years and this has never happened before Luciano - I just want to know how to stop it.

Comment: I am only using photos for my own use Scott, so rarely use Raw as it uses a lot of memory.

Comment: @close voters: How is this not with the expertise of graphic designers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you have "Delete Cropped Pixels" selected in the tool bar. Once checked, PS will keep the image flattened by default and delete the pixels.

[image: Delete Cropped Pixels]

Comment: @BabsBurnell, you should "accept" the answer if you feel it fixed the issue. When the original poster doesn't interact at all and say why the suggested answer(s) don't cut it or if the OP doesn't accept an answer but comments with thanks... it can give the impression that this answer was what they were looking because many new users overlook this accepting thing. Also... in such case, you are less likely to get more answers. There's a small help article about this: https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: Awesome. Thanks (again - 2nd time this year). :-)